# 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a statement like so:

```
var vals =
    from StandAloneUserPayment saup in _Session.Query<StandAloneUserPayment>()
        .Fetch(x => x.RecurringPayments)
    where
        saup.User.UserId == userId
        && searchString.Contains(saup.FriendlyName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    select
        saup;
```

This seems to be exactly what I'm supposed to do, but I get the  whole line with the `Contains` method underlined with the following message:

> `string` does not contain a definition for `Contains` and the best extension method overload `System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TSource>)` has some invalid arguments

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `IndexOf`:

```
searchString.IndexOf(saup.FriendlyName,
                     StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1
```

The reason it doesn't work is because the `Contains` extension method that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` is operating on a `String`, which implements `IEnumerable<char>`, not `IEnumerable<string>`, so a `string` and an `IEqualityComparer<string>` can't be passed to it.

Comment: My intellisense would argue with you.  It tells me I have three overloads.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: And one of them takes a `StringComparer`? (Sorry, I can't try it right now, but MSDN is usually right...)

Comment: as the error message implies, it takes an `IEqualityComparer`, which StringComparer implements.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs - are you sure you aren't using some kind of third party extension that supplies additional methods?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs extenstion methods?

Comment: I think this is part of Linq.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Right... that's odd. Well, try `IndexOf` anyway.

Comment: My intellisense said this: `(extention) bool IEnumerable<char>.Contains(char value, IEqualityComparer<char> comparer)`

Comment: @minitech Changing it to `IndexOf` gets me "The best overloaded method match for 'string.IndexOf(string, System.StringComparison)' has some invalid arguments"... I am scratching my head on this.

Comment: Hah never mind I'm an idiot; `IndexOf` works if I change the `StringComparer` to `StringComparison`... `Contains` still doesn't work though.  Well, it's good enough for me, thanks.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Is `saup.UserPayment` actually a `string`?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Oh yeah, and I just realized the reason `Contains` doesn't work; `String.Contains` is a special case because a `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`, not an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @minitech Can you expand your answer to explain?  It might be useful for the next person scratching their head.  I am marking this as the answer; thanks.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Sure, sorry.

Comment: Then what the hell is this sirs?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole: Documentation for a method called `Contains` on `String` that takes one argument, the second of which, it follows, is not an `IEqualityComparer<string>`.

Answer (score 3):

Even if there is a [Contains(source, item, comparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341422.aspx) method, you can't* use that with NHibernate, as comparers are code, not expression trees that NH can translate.

*: that is, unless you write a LINQ provider extension that special-cases generation for your comparer, but that's not the case.

Comment: Odd that the intellisense lead me right into the problem.  The IndexOf worked for what I needed, but it seems like that should work.

Answer (score 2):

The .Contains you are using comes from LINQ - it sees the String as an `IEnumerable<char>`, so it wants an `IEqualityComparer<char>`.  The `StringComparer` comparers implement `IEqualityComparer<String>`.

If minitech's `IndexOf` method works, I think that will be the easiest way.

Answer (score -4):

Add following namespace to your class,

```
using System.Linq;
```

Hope it helps.